# Netezza SQL: Check if two tables are identical

Tags: sql, r

I am working with Netezza SQL.

Suppose I have two tables:

```
### TABLE1

  var1 var2
1    1    a
2    1    b
3    1    c

## TABLE2

  var1 var2
1    1    a
2    1    b
3    1    c
```

If I was using the R programming language, I could have easily verified that these two tables are identical:

```
> identical(table1, table2)
[1] TRUE
```

**My Question:** Is it possible to do something similar in Netezza SQL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Set operators](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/netezza?topic=objects-combine-tables-union-intersect-except) can be used to find the differences between two tables.

`EXCEPT ALL` removes the same rows from the second result set from the first result set, this has to be run in both orders to get all differences. `UNION ALL` merges the two results sets together. If any rows are returned, they aren't the same. `COUNT(*) = 0` will return this as a boolean.

```sql
-- Example data and table names with a CTE, this isn't required.
WITH TABLE1 (var1, var2) AS (
    VALUES (1, 'a'), (1,'b'), (1,'c')
),
TABLE2 (var1, var2) AS (
    VALUES (1, 'a'), (1,'b'), (1,'c')
)

-- Compare these tables
SELECT COUNT(*) = 0 AS IS_IDENTICAL FROM
(
    (
        SELECT * FROM TABLE1
        EXCEPT ALL
        SELECT * FROM TABLE2 
    )
    UNION ALL
    (
        SELECT * FROM TABLE2
        EXCEPT ALL
        SELECT * FROM TABLE1 
    )
)
;
```

Output:

| IS_IDENTICAL |
| --- |
| true |